# Add Hyperlinks to this VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, directory

The VBA below allows a user to select a folder, then the full paths are displayed in column 1 of the active sheet.

How would I modify it for those paths to work as hyperlinks?

```
Option Explicit
Sub cmdList()
    Dim sPath   As String
    Dim fOut    As Variant
    Dim r       As Integer
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select directory"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
        sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    fOut = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & sPath & """ /a:-h-s /b /s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
    r = 5
    Range(r & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
   Cells(r, 1).Resize(UBound(fOut) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fOut)
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your code gets the full filespec already, we can use the data to complete `=HYPERLINK()` formulas:

```
Sub cmdList()
    Dim sPath   As String
    Dim fOut    As Variant
    Dim r       As Integer

    Dim Cell As Range

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select directory"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
        sPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    fOut = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & sPath & """ /a:-h-s /b /s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
    r = 5
    Range(r & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
   Cells(r, 1).Resize(UBound(fOut) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fOut)

   '*************************************************************

   Dim dq As String,  rng As Range
   dq = Chr(34)

   Set Rng = Cells(r, 1).Resize(UBound(fOut) + 1, 1)
   For Each Cell In Rng
        Cell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & dq & Cell.Value & dq & "," & dq & Cell.Value & dq & ")"
   Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: You are a fine Padawan, Gary's Student! Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

add the code above the "End sub" syntax. The following code will change the Activecell value to hyperlink

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Activecell, Activecell.Value

I hope it is helpfull for you.